# What's the simplest way to write a program/script to remove the same string from the beginning of a bunch of file names?

Tags: python, windows

I have a bunch of mp3's that all have a long title, followed by "part 3" or "part 4", etc. So it's like "aasasdfjklakjsdf - part 3" and "aasasdfjklakjsdf - part 4" and "aasasdfjklakjsdf - part 5" and so on.

I have over 100 of these and I would like to simply remove the "aasasdfjklakjsdf - " part from the title of each one. I have a CS degree so I know the basics of programming, but I've never actually written a script of any kind and would love to get started. I'm wondering what the fastest and easiest way to go about doing something like this is. I'm running windows 7. I'm guessing something with python maybe? Or is there something I could do from the windows command prompt?

Comment: There are a variety of different `rename` programs written in Python and Perl that can do what you want, most of which should work on Windows, so it would just be a matter of typing, e.g., `rename.py "aasasdfjklakjsdf - " "" aasasdfjklakjsdf*.mp3`. I don't have a specific one to recommend (when I want to do this on Windows, I do it through Cygwin, so I only know whichever one Cygwin calls `rename`…), but you should be able to google them pretty quickly.

Comment: What university did you get your CS degree from???

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to use Python, which I think is a good choice, you'll use the `glob` module to get all the file names and the `os` module to rename the files. You'll want to figure out what delimeter you're looking for. In Python, strings have a `split` method. For each file name, split the file name at the delimeter, and rename the file using the second field from the split.

This is a very broad description of what you'll need to do. Best of luck!

Comment: Good job explaining the parts needed without giving the answer away.

Comment: Thanks. It's literally 3 lines of Python (not counting the 2 lines needed to import each module on its own line). If I had a CS degree, I would be ashamed to copy and paste this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my advice, first go ahead and install python and then also [ipython](http://ipython.org/).

Now go into ipython and try in the interactive interpreter something like this:

```
import os
cd C:/my_dir/
trimstr = 'aasasdfjklakjsdf - '
for x in os.listdir('.'):
  if x.startswith(trimstr):
    oldname = x
    newname = x[len(trimstr):]
    print oldname, ' -> ', newname 
    if os.path.exists(newname):
      print 'skipping', x, 'because the new name would stomp an existing file'
    else:
      pass
      #os.rename(oldname, newname)
  else:
    print 'ignoring', x
```

You can copy my codeblock and paste it into ipython if you're lazy, but change the line cd `'C:/my_dir/'` into `os.chdir(...)` substituting in the actual directory you want to work on.

At this stage, it will just chat to stdout the changes which will be made.  So run that, and if all looks good, go ahead and uncomment the `#commented line` and do it for real.  You can rerun what you just entered into ipython by using the up arrow.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write a script for this operation, just use powershell (which is built into Windows).

Powershell has a Rename-Item commandlet ([Microsoft Docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315353.aspx)) which you can use the following way:

`Dir | Rename-Item –NewName {$_.name –replace "_What_You_Want_Replaced_","_Replacement_"}`

e.g.

```
>powershell
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS cd "your mp3 folder"
PS Dir | Rename-Item –NewName {$_.name –replace "aasasdfjklakjsdf -",""}
```

Done and done. It's that easy.